# AudioContext.createAnalyser auto gain?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Does the [fft analyser have some sort of auto adjusting gain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode)? You can see in this demo (using Chrome or Firefox) that the spectrum will seem to adjust and flatten down to zero rather than remain at a constant height.

I suppose adjusting the gain could make audio visualizers look better, but its certainly not good for DSP when you need the real gain values.

In this demo, I'm using the microphone audio input and displaying the spectrum. If you change the volume that you're playing through the speakers, you'll see the spectrum change, but then slowly adjust to the new loudness.

The point is, playing pink noise (or white noise) louder or softer produces the same exact spectrum after an initial transient. I would expect playing music louder to be reflected in the spectrum.

Any ideas how to get around this so I can plot the real spectrum?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pink Noise</title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="spectrum"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

var initAudio, microphoneError, microphoneSuccess, pinkNoise;

navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

window.requestAnimationFrame = (window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame);

microphoneError = function(event) {
  console.log("error")
  if (event.name === "PermissionDeniedError") {
    alert("This app requires a microphone as input. Please adjust your privacy settings.");
  }
};

microphoneSuccess = function(stream) {
  console.log("success")
  initAudio(stream);
};

pinkNoise = function(context) {
  console.log("starting pink noise")
  var b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, bufferSize, pinkNode;
  bufferSize = 4096;
  b0 = b1 = b2 = b3 = b4 = b5 = b6 = 0.0;
  pinkNode = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
  pinkNode.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
    var i, output, white, _i, _results;
    output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    _results = [];
    for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= bufferSize ? _i < bufferSize : _i > bufferSize; i = 0 <= bufferSize ? ++_i : --_i) {
      white = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
      b0 = 0.99886 * b0 + white * 0.0555179;
      b1 = 0.99332 * b1 + white * 0.0750759;
      b2 = 0.96900 * b2 + white * 0.1538520;
      b3 = 0.86650 * b3 + white * 0.3104856;
      b4 = 0.55000 * b4 + white * 0.5329522;
      b5 = -0.7616 * b5 - white * 0.0168980;
      output[i] = b0 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 + white * 0.5362;
      output[i] *= 0.11;
      _results.push(b6 = white * 0.115926);
    }
  };
  pinkNode.connect(context.destination);
};


initAudio = function(stream) {
  console.log("init audio")
  var analyser, bufferLength, canvas, canvasElement, context, dataArray, draw, filterNode, height, sourceNode, width;

  canvasElement = document.getElementById("spectrum");
  width = 1000;
  height = 400;

  canvasElement.width = width;
  canvasElement.height = height;
  canvas = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
  context = new AudioContext();

  sourceNode = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

  filterNode = context.createBiquadFilter();
  filterNode.type = filterNode.LOWPASS;
  filterNode.frequency.value = 4410;
  filterNode.Q.value = 1.5;
  filterNode.gain.value = 0;

  sourceNode.connect(filterNode);

  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  analyser.fftSize = 2048;

  filterNode.connect(analyser);

  bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
  canvas.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  pinkNoise(context);

  draw = function() {
    var barHeight, barWidth, drawVisual, i, x, _i, _results;
    drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
    canvas.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    canvas.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    barWidth = (width / bufferLength) * 2.5;
    x = 0;
    _results = [];
    for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= bufferLength ? _i < bufferLength : _i > bufferLength; i = 0 <= bufferLength ? ++_i : --_i) {
      barHeight = dataArray[i] / 255 * height;
      canvas.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,50,50)';
      canvas.fillRect(x, height - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
      _results.push(x += barWidth + 1);
    }
    _results;
  };
  draw();
};

window.onload = function() {
  console.log("here")
  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    console.log("get microphone");
    navigator.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    }, microphoneSuccess, microphoneError);
  } else {
    alert("This app requires a microphone as input. Please try using Chrome or Firefox.");
  }
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Chet: I'm really not sure what you mean here. When you say "try changing the volume", do you mean the microphone input volume – or the value of one of your gain nodes?

Comment: the volume that your playing through the speakers. I edited the post to elaborate a little more on that.

Comment: The exact operation of the AnalyserNode is defined in the spec. There is some amount of smoothing that happens, but the spec doesn't imply adding any compression/expansion in the AnalyzerNode. See http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#fft-windowing-and-smoothing-over-time

Comment: If you are curious, the exact DSP operations that are performed in the AnalyserNode can be seen in the source code. Here is the source for Chrome. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/webaudio/RealtimeAnalyser.cpp&sq=package:chromium

Comment: hmm interesting. why am I getting down-votes for this post?

Comment: So you're creating pink noise and playing it back through your loudspeakers and getting your microphone to pick it up. I created a JSFiddle based on your code. http://jsfiddle.net/notthetup/gfbou158/2/.

Comment: I totally missed this. This might be because of the automatic gain control on your microphone in your OS. Do you have that turned on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely due to automatic gain control setting in your operating system sound settings.

On OSX, the Sound Preferences have a "Use ambient noise reduction" setting in the "Input" tab. Turning that off fixed the issue for me.

[image: osx sound preferences]